# How to right align a UIStackView inside a UIScrollView when the stack view's size is smaller than scroll view?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

Please look at the below picture of my storyboard to understand the layout of my views.

[image]

On the left side is a horizontal `UIStackView` with 2 buttons. This is okay.

On the right side of the above stack view is a `UIScrollView` which has a horizontal `UIStackView` inside it.

I basically want the right stack view to be able to have many buttons in it.

If the right stack view's size exceeds the scroll view's width, then it should be scrollable to show remaining buttons.

This works fine so far and I was able to achieve this by setting the right stack view's edges to the `contentLayoutGuide` of the parent scroll view and setting the right stack view's height equal to the `frameLayoutGuide` of the parent scroll view.

This allows me to scroll successfully if there are too many buttons.

The problem I am facing is that if there's only a few buttons to not be enough to be scrollable, then I want those buttons to be right aligned. Basically, the `UIScrollView` should align the content stack view on the right side. Currently, all buttons are aligned to the left side.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution after posting my question.

1. I added an extra view at the beginning of the right `UIStackView`. This is basically a spacer view with no constraints and background color set to transparent. It is important NOT to set it to hidden and instead use transparent background color because `UIStackView` don't render hidden views and then this solution won't work. With this said, for this Stack Overflow answer, I have this view's background color set to purple to make things easier to understand.
2. I added a new `width` constraint on the right `UIStackView` and made it greater than or equal to `frameLayoutGuide` width.

Here's how it looks:

[image]